# Does BaseX support running a basex script file (.bxs) with the jobs module or a combination of query with proc module and jobs module?

Tags: service, command-line, scheduler, jobs, basex

This has been a thorn in my side and I'm wondering if I'm missing something simple or not.  I need to run .bxs scripts from the jobs scheduler.

I tried to start a service with a .bxs script file from the jobs module but it does not run.  It registers as a service but the script does not run.

```
let $home := Q{org.basex.util.Prop}HOMEDIR()
let $job :=  $home || 'webapp/sync/update_jira.bxs'
let $job2 := $home || 'webapp/sync/update_commit_data.bxs'
return (jobs:eval(xs:anyURI($job), (), map { 'id':'update_jira_job', 'start':'14:54:02', 'interval':'P1D', 'service': true(), 'log': 'update_jira_job'}),
jobs:eval(xs:anyURI($job2), (), map { 'id':'update_commit_data', 'start':'15:03:02', 'interval':'P1D', 'service': true(), 'log': 'update_commit_data'}))
```

I also tried to run a query that executes the command line to run the scripts for example within the update_jira.xq there is a line proc:execute('basex update_jira.bxs') from an initial query that looks something like this...

```
let $home := Q{org.basex.util.Prop}HOMEDIR()
let $job :=  $home || '/srv/webapp/sync/update_jira.xq'
let $job2 := $home || '/src/webapp/sync/update_commit_data.xq'
return (jobs:eval(xs:anyURI($job), (), map { 'id':'update_jira_job', 'start':'14:54:02', 'interval':'P1D', 'service': true(), 'log': 'update_jira_job'}),
jobs:eval(xs:anyURI($job2), (), map { 'id':'update_commit_data', 'start':'15:03:02', 'interval':'P1D', 'service': true(), 'log': 'update_commit_data'}))
```

When this ran as a service, the database did not update as expected and I got this output in the log:

```
22:47:02.001    JOB:update_commit_data  admin   OK  0.30    update_commit_data
22:41:00.000    JOB:update_jira_job admin   ERROR   0.00    update_jira_job; Unexpected end of query: '0'.
```

But that is strange because when I ran the query itself -- that starts the service with jobs:eval -- then it actually ran ok when I ran the query for the first time.

```
16:42:52.257    10.244.144.142:57444    admin   200 221563.70   [GET] /rest?run=sync/update_jira.bxs
16:49:39.862    10.244.144.142:57591    admin   200 101413.21   [GET] /rest?run=sync/update_commit_data.bxs
```

This is my latest attempt where the query runs initially but then doesn't seem to execute as a service interval.  I added the base-uri as the path to the query and I hope that's the right way to do that.

```
let $home := Q{org.basex.util.Prop}HOMEDIR()
return jobs:eval(proc:execute('/usr/local/bin/basex', '/srv/basex/webapp/sync/update_jira.bxs'), (), 
                  map { 'id':'update_jira_job', 'interval':'PT5M', 'base-uri': '/srv/basex/webapp/sync/', 
                  'service': true(), 'log': 'update_jira_job'})
```

When I run this through the database admin tool query window, it runs right away

```
14:02:54.494    10.244.144.142:54402    admin   200 296095.32   [POST] /dba/query-update
```

And then after 5 the minute interval a .05 ms log entry shows up when the service kicked off:

```
14:57:50.564    JOB:update_jira_job admin   OK  0.05    update_jira_job
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that BaseX command scripts contain plain database commands, whereas the functions in the Jobs Module were tailored to execute XQuery code. If you want to use `jobs:eval`, the best solution is to rewrite the contents of your command scripts to XQuery.

If you want to stick with the command scripts, you could indeed try to invoke BaseX via `proc:execute`, but you should be aware that the two BaseX instance will run independently of each other and could lead to corrupt databases (see https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Startup#Concurrent_Operations).

If the invocation fails…

```
Cannot run program "basex": CreateProcess error=2, ...
```

…you may need to address BaseX with the full path:

```
(: Windows installation :)
proc:execute('c:\Program Files (x86)\BaseX\bin\basex.bat', 'commands.bxs')
(: Linux :)
proc:execute('/path/to/basex', 'commands.bxs')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and confirming that the Jobs module runs queries only and not command scripts.  The documentation states this too but I just wanted to be certain.  I'm wondering if running command scripts from the Jobs module is functionality that could be added or not?

Comment: Regardless - the path for me is not the problem because the initial query with the jobs:eval actually runs via the proc:execute but when it tries to run as a service, that's when the ERROR is seen in the log as indicated in the initial question.  That may be a bug or just something that is not supported because it seems like if these queries run initially then they should run as a service.  I may be out of luck here.  The scripts are over 50 lines long where database documents are deleted and then added as blank and many update queries need to run in sequence.

Comment: Feel free to write to the basex-talk mailing list, it may be a better place to understand and resolve this issue.